# Calculate difference in Column B when there is a Match in Column A

Tags: python, pandas

I would the differences in Column B between DF 1 and DF 2 based on string matches in Column A. The data frames have hundreds of rows and may not be in order. They look something like this:

```
df1

     A    B
0  a,b  2.0
1  d,c  1.4
2  a,c  1.8
3  c,d  5.4
4  m,m  2.0

df2

     A    B
0  c,d  2.1
1  a,b  2.2
2  k,k  3.0
3  a,d  2.0
4  m,m  1.2
```

and the desired output would be based on DF 1 and return NaN if there is no match. It would look like:

```
            DF Result                         
    __|  A   |   B   |             
    0 |'a,b' | -0.2  |             
    1 |'d,c' |  NaN  |             
    2 |'a,c' |  NaN  |              
    3 |'c,d' |  3.3  |             
    4 |'m,m' |  0.8  |
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform index-aligned subtraction.

```
(df1.set_index('A').B - df2.set_index('A').reindex(df1.A).B).reset_index()

     A    B
0  a,b -0.2
1  d,c  NaN
2  a,c  NaN
3  c,d  3.3
4  m,m  0.8
```

Comment: Fantastic!! Thank you COLDSPEED!